# couchdb user manager GUI

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant

I'm currently using couchdb hosted on [cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) (thanks cloudant guys! You're great!).
I've many users in my database (which is [here](http://epos-couch.cloudant.com/epos-couch/_design/epos-couch/index.html)), and now I manage them maually: I've a script on my linux box which generates users/pass json object, like that

```
{
    "_id": "org.couchdb.user:MY_USER",
    "_rev": "1-7aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2783",
    "name": "MY_USER",
    "type": "user",
    "roles": ["admin"],
    "password_sha": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "salt": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

(removed real string and substituded with 'XXX...' of course).

I then paste this object in the _user database and everything works fine.

However, as it happens to frequently to remove, update user information, I was wandering if anybody created a couchdb GUI for user management. 
Something really simple, like the phpmyadmin GUI:

[image: mysqul GUI user manager page]

I googled and stackoverflowed around to search for something like this, but found nothing.

Does something like that already exist?

(and if not, do you think there is a special reason? Couchdb is widespread and I don't think I'm the first one who had to face this issue...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the most easy and common way to edit and maintain user information is from the couchdb admin gui called futon. You can access it at

`http://localhost:5984/_utils/database.html?_users`

While it is not an ideal user management tool, it gets the job done.

I have not seen a nice gui for doing the user management. It is a good idea. We are currently in the process of working on the next admin gui for couchdb called 'fauxton' were we will try and make this more user friendly.

Comment: Hi Ryan,thanks for your answer. I know futon (forgot to mention in my question). I was hoping something more user friendly was available. In any case, there is some probability that I'll do that by myself and put it on github: the "engine" (generation of password an json objects) is ready, I just have to code the GUI. let's see if I find some time...